# Is it possible to set the color and other controls for a literal control in code in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am coding a dynamic asp.net page in which i want to have text boxes in a page and the number of text boxes depend on a previous user input. Since the number of text boxes are decided dynamically, I am going with designing them in code rather than in the aspx page.Now I need these fields to be mandatory and so want to indicate a RED asterisk symbol in front of the label corresponding to each text box.I am really new to working in .net and I couldn't figure out how to set a specific color to a labelcontrol. I found the following syntax while doing a google search but it didnt help.

```
Dim asteric As New LiteralControl() 
asteric.Text = "<font color\"red\">*</font>"
```

I am not sure whether i am missing something very small here.I really appreciate any help in this issue.

Comment: asteric.ForeColor = Color.Red, or similar.

Comment: Label controls have the ForeColor property, but not Literals.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson : I changed my control as a label and used the ForeColor property and it worked. But as Goran Mottram mentioned, there is no ForeColor property associated with LiteralControl.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The VB code is fine, the HTML it's trying to produce is not. You're missing an `=` symbol:

```
asteric.Text = "<font color=\"red\">*</font>"
```

Comment: Seeing as you got it right. have another +1. Never even noticed the bad html